# How to delete object from many-to-many relationship entities

Tags: hibernate, groovy, micronaut

I want to delete one dashboard and checking also whether it is present in dashboardGroup list then delete it from dashboard group as well.

both entities dashboard and dashboardGroup having many to many relationship, Check below code:

```
if(params.id){
     def dashboard = Dashboard.get(params.id)
     if (dashboard) {
        def dashboardGroups = dashboard.dashboardGroups
        for(DashboardGroup dashGroup : dashboardGroups){
           dashboard.removeFromDashboardGroups(dashGroup)
        }
        dashboard.delete() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(params.id) {
   def dashboard = Dashboard.get(params.id)
   if (dashboard) {
       dashboard.dashboardGroups*.remove(dashboard)
       dashboard.delete()
 }
```

Comment: Above solution giving this error 
**groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.ef.Domains.DashboardGroup.remove() is applicable for argument types: (com.ef.Domains.Dashboard)**

Comment: what type of dashboardGroups?

Comment: Its an object derived from domain class.

Comment: It is recommended that you include some explanation along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OrphanRemoval for that. Eg.:

```
public class Dashboard {

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Set<DashboardGroup> dashboardGroups = new HashSet<DashboardGroup>();

}
```

When you try:

```
Dashboard dashboard = entityManager.find(Dashboard.class, 1L);
entityManager.remove(dashboard);
```

it will delete associated `dashboardGroups` .